# storing logged user data from front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, laravel, mongodb

I'm using `angularjs` to front-end and `laravel` framework to back-end. my database is `Mysql`.
I need to store all user's logs. Since I don't want to store user's logs inside mysql I chose `MongoDB`.
now I don't want to use `laravel` to store user's logs,Instead, I want to use `nodejs`.

**At a glance:**

laravel - mysql   : to store data

nodejs  - mongoDB : to store user's logs

**My question,**

I want to send user's logs from `angularjs` to `nodejs` and storing them inside `mongoDB`. 
I think most systems stores user's logs from server-side(here laravel to mongodb or mysql),but I send user's logs from front-end to `nodejs` to storing logs. of course the connection between `angularjs` and `nodejs` has a hashing method.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this method?

Comment: What do you mean with logs, do you mean login credentials or something else?

Comment: All the actions the user do. (login,pages,add,edit ... )

Comment: is a good idea,

Comment: You can never make something too complicated. Two backend frameworks and two backend database engines is a good start. How about two front-end frameworks each with there own router and add jQuery UI-Components as well. Wouldn't hurt to add some REST layers. Maybe both Restangular and ngResource.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a framework that logs all kinds of user actions from the front end JS app to an ajax call.  For performance reasons it is based on asynchronous evenrs and buffers actions until some number are queued (generally 10) or a window close event.  This data is stored in a back end database (ours is a fixed SQL schema so we have normalized all logs to a specific format).

We have found this a very good debugging and auditing tool.  It does consume a modest amount of bandwidth and we only have a few hundred simultaneous users, but I would think with a good server design it could scale well (we use two sets of servers in two data centers).

It does help to classify the "actions" so we have some nav actions for focus changes, some api actions for other ajax calls, error logs for anything unusual, some input actions for form data edits, etc.  We always log a session id, the user id, timestamp, etc.  Best part is the framework does it all and the app writer does not need to think about it unless they explicitly want to call a logging function.

Your mileage will vary based on your requirements/environment, but it works very well for us.